# Laravel 4.2 Uploading file in specific folder

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4

Hi im creating a project in laravel 4.2 that uploads different files (e.g Pdf and images) in specific folders about 8 or 9 folders to be exact i just try the do a if statement but dont know what happend but its not working and there are no error displayed when i execute the code. please help me work this code or do you have any idea to simplify my code TIA!

Here's my code in my controller

```
public function upload()
    {
        $finame = Input::get('name');
        $ftype = Input::get('type');
        $username = Input::get('user');
        $desc = Input::get('desc');
        $date = Input::get('date');
        $upload = Input::file('file');
        $add = Files::upload2($finame,$ftype,$username,$desc,$date,$upload);


        if ($add == true && $ftype == "pf") {
            $upload -> move(public_path('pf'),$upload->getClientOriginalName());
            return \Response::json(array('success' => true));
            return Redirect::to('/home')->with('message', 'message|Record Successfully Added.');
        } elseif ($add == true && $ftype == "sf") {
            $upload -> move(public_path('sf'),$upload->getClientOriginalName());
            return \Response::json(array('success' => true));
            return Redirect::to('/home')->with('message', 'message|Record Successfully Added.');
        } } elseif ($add == true && $ftype == "gale") {
            $upload -> move(public_path('gale'),$upload->getClientOriginalName());
            return \Response::json(array('success' => true));
            return Redirect::to('/home')->with('message', 'message|Record Successfully Added.');
        } } elseif ($add == true && $ftype == "advisory") {
            $upload -> move(public_path('advisory'),$upload->getClientOriginalName());
            return \Response::json(array('success' => true));
            return Redirect::to('/home')->with('message', 'message|Record Successfully Added.');
        } else {
            return Redirect::back()->with('message', 'error|Error');
        }

    }
```

And my code in model:

```
public static function upload2($finame,$ftype,$username,$desc,$date,$upload)
    {

        $files = new self;
        $files->file_name = $finame;
        $files->file_type = $ftype;
        $files->username = $username;
        $files->description = $desc;
        $files->date = $date;
        $files->upload = $upload->getClientOriginalName();
        try {
            $files->save();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            dd($e);
        }
    }
```

and in the view add this script:

```
<script>
var form = document.getElementById('upload');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formdata = new FormData(form);

    request.open('post', '/upload');
    request.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
    request.send(formdata);

});

function transferComplete(data){
    response = JSON.parse(data.currentTarget.response);
    if(response.success){
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = "File Successfully Uploaded!";
    }
}
</script>
```